# Best adb command and system tweaks for non rooted phone to get closer to rooted experience

Tags: adb, root-access

As I always owned rooted phones I find frustrating living with all the limitations of non-rooted phones.

I would like to list here all the adb commands you can issue and system settings you can tweak to get your non-rooted phone experience closer to a rooted one. In a way decreasing "security" when connected to a PC.

Especially targeting Android 10+

Of course we all know everything starts enabling `Developer Options` and `USB Debug`

I can execute some `pm disable package` or `pm uninstall package` to get rid of some bloat system apps.

Then I can do some `setting put global parameter n` to tweak some system settings.
I.E. `setting put global dropbox_max_files 9` limits the number of files in `/data/system/dropbox` directory (unaccessible) to 9 instead of hundreds (if not thousands).
[Dropbox app not installed, but there is log activity in /data/system/dropbox](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/dropbox-app-not-installed-but-there-is-log-activity-in-data-system-dropbox/218147#218147)

Finally there's `pm grant com.package.name android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` to play with...

Comment: [content query](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228746)

Comment: [/data/local/tmp/busybox](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215678)

Comment: Our [adb tag wiki](/tags/adb/info) links to several good resources. "Get closer to root experience" is a bit vague; if you could include what especially you want to achieve, it would be easier to answer. "list here all the adb commands…" ahem: [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154)… But well, good luck!